# Gunicorn failed Triggered by gunicorn.socket: Failed with result 'exit-code'. error

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying out a simple Django deployment app on VPS using this [url](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04#creating-and-configuring-a-new-django-project). I went through every step of the work and successfully ran this project via python manage.py runserver where there isn't a mistake, but when I try to implement it with unicorn its launch following error

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-16 11:28:04 CET; 22h ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 5578 (code=exited, status=2)

Warning: journal has been rotated since the unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

Here are the files

*nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

*nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pawnhost/page_builder
ExecStart=/home/pawnhost/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind /run/gunicorn.sock \
          pawnhost.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*systemctl status gunicorn.socket*

```
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Thu 2022-03-17 09:58:53 CET; 25min ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Mar 17 09:58:53 website.com systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

*systemctl status gunicorn*

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-16 11:28:04 CET; 23h ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 5578 (code=exited, status=2)

Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```